# Nvidia GeForce GT 750M Driver issue (black Screen or login loop)

Tags: graphics, lenovo, nvidia-optimus

I am trying to set up the Nvidia Driver on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for my Lenovo Y510P Laptop. My laptop has a Nvidia Optimus Technology graphics card (GeForece GT 750M). I have tried using all of the additional Nvidia Drivers including current to old, 415, 410, 396, 390, and 340 (with ppa:graphics-drivers). I have tried using Bumblebee (which is no longer available using ppa:bumblebee/stable), I have tried changing .conf files, I have tried using bbswitch, Prime and others, but no luck. I either get a black screen with a blinking cursor in the top left corner, or a Login loop.

I have spent 5 days searching this and other forums trying to find a solution, but after trying dozens of different solution attempts, nothing works. Unfortunately, all forum topics I have found up to this point are very outdated and provide old solutions to additional software such as Bumblebee that is no longer available or updated. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember you just have to follow the instructions here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee. For the sake of completeness I am just copying the relevant part in the next lines:

1. Enable the Universe and Multiverse repositories in order to allow the bumblebee and nvidia packages to be installed
2. Do `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic` at your terminal
3. Reboot.

Then read the "usage" subsection in the same link.

Comment: As you have tried everything already...I would recommend you to start again with a fresh installation.

Comment: Check out https://bumblebee-project.org/